# Video format Timecode for avplayer ios

Tags: ios, avplayer, cmtime, timecodes

I'm trying to make a video timecode with a "video format":
 MM:SS:FF

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it yet but It might work

```
MM = totalFrames / (60*framerate)%60
SS = totalFrames / framerate % 60
FF = totalFrames % framerate
```